# Vue 3: computed property doesn't track its dependency in composition API

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

Consider this illustrative example:

```js
const App = {
 setup() {
  const name = Vue.ref("");
  let firstTime = true;
  const message = Vue.computed(() => {
    if (firstTime) {
      firstTime = false;
      return "Welcome stranger";
    }
    return `Hello ${name.value}`;
  });
  
  return {
    name,
    message
  }
 }
};

Vue.createApp(App).mount("#root");
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
<div id="root">
  name: <input v-model="name"/> <br/>
  message: {{ message }}
</div>
```

As you can see, `message` stores a *computed* value that should track updates to `name` but it isn't.
Why is it like that and how to fix it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Computed should always use an immutable reactive ref object you want to be computed.

so if you declare the reactive objects you are using at the beginning it will work.

```js
const App = {
 setup() {
  const name = Vue.ref("");
  let firstTime = true;
  const message = Vue.computed(() => {
    name.value;
    if (firstTime) {
      firstTime = false;
      return "Welcome stranger";
    }
    return `Hello ${name.value}`;
  });
  
  return {
    name,
    message
  }
 }
};

Vue.createApp(App).mount("#root");
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
<div id="root">
  name: <input v-model="name"/> <br/>
  message: {{ message }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

This is because Vue **cannot** discover the dependency between your computed property `message` and the ref `name` if you write it this way. The problem is the `firstTime` variable.

What is going on is that Vue discovers dependency at **runtime** (instead of compile time) by **running** the computed property and **observing** what reactive references are **accessed** during the process:

- your computed property needs to be given a chance to at least run **once**. Vue ensures it by running it immediately when it is registered.
- during the execution of your computed property, reactive ref needs to be **accessed**. This is broken for you because `name.value` is not accessed the first time your computed property runs. And because during the first run no reactive ref is accessed at all, your computed property will never be triggered again.

It is fine if you don't access the name.value for the first time, but you need to access something else that is reactive and will change when firstTime becomes false:

```js
const App = {
 setup() {
  const name = Vue.ref("");
  const firstTime = Vue.ref(true);

  Vue.watch(()=> name.value, ()=>{firstTime.value=false;});

  const message = Vue.computed(() => {
   
    if (firstTime.value) {
      return "Welcome stranger";
    }
    return `Hello ${name.value}`;
  });
  
  return {
    name,
    message
  }
 }
};

Vue.createApp(App).mount("#root");
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
<div id="root">
  name: <input v-model="name"/> <br/>
  message: {{ message }}
</div>
```

Comment: nice explanation but adding a watcher here is an overkill (at least you should unwatch it after `firstTime.value = false` because it's no longer needed).

Comment: @marzelin right, and this is really just to illustrate the mechanism. That being said, if you watch something but that thing never changes after the first mutation, it really does not make a difference whether you stop the watch or not.

Comment: yes, but here you're watching `name` which changes on user input, not just once.

Comment: @marzelin ah i see. thought the watch is on firstTime. In this case you are right

Answer (score 3):

Assign `name.value` to a variable in the beginning of computed property then return it at the end

```js
const App = {
 setup() {
  const name = Vue.ref("");
  let firstTime =true
  const message = Vue.computed(() => {
  let _name=name.value
    if (firstTime) {
      firstTime= false;
      return "Welcome stranger";
    }
    return `Hello ${_name}`;
  });
  
  return {
    name,
    message
  }
 }
};

Vue.createApp(App).mount("#root");
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
<div id="root">
  name: <input v-model="name" /> <br/> message: {{ message }} <br/> name:{{name}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

In this particular example when different results are expected on initial render we can use `watch` instead of `computed` since `watch` is lazy by default and won't be executed on initial render (only when its dependency: `name` changes) and that's exactly what is needed here.

```js
const App = {
  setup() {
    const name = Vue.ref("");

    Vue.watch(name, () => state.message = `Hello ${name.value}`);

    const state = {
      name,
      message: "Welcome stranger"
    };
    return state;
  }
};

Vue.createApp(App).mount("#root");
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
<div id="root">
  name: <input v-model="name" /> <br/> message: {{ message }}
</div>
```